# Unable to start ReactiveWebApplicationContext due to missing ReactiveWebServerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a new springboot application I am attempting to get started.

The error I receive is

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start reactive web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ReactiveWebApplicationContext due to missing ReactiveWebServerFactory bean.
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:76) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
```

**src/main/java/bubbleshadow/RootController.java**

```
package bubbleshadow;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
public class RootController {
  public RootController() {

  }

  @GetMapping("/")
  public Mono<HttpStatus> returnOk() {
    return Mono.just(HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

**src/test/java/test/bubbleshadow/RootControllerTest.java**

```
package test.bubbleshadow;
import bubbleshadow.RootController;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
// import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.AutoConfigureWebTestClient;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=RootController.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class RootControllerTest {
  @Autowired
  WebTestClient webTestClient;

  @Test
  public void baseRouteShouldReturnStatusOK() {
    webTestClient.head().uri("/").exchange().expectStatus().isOk();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Your configuration is not sufficient for reactive tests.

The reactive `WebTestClient` as well as `ReactiveWebApplicationContext` need reactive server in the application context. Add annotation `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to your `RootControllerTest` and let Spring's do it for you.

The autoconfiguration searches your class path and after find reactive classes and reactive context then create `ReactiveWebServerFactory` bean.

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot version 2.2.5.RELEASE, and I also had to add the classes explicitly to the `@SpringBootTest` annotation (even though they were annotated with `@Configuration` and `@Component` respectively):

`@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
    classes = {FooConfig.class, FooHandler.class})`

Comment: I guess maybe a `@ComponentScan` annotation with the appropriate packages might do the trick as well.

Answer (score 15):

I assume you are using maven to get your dependencies.

I solved the problem by using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Instead of:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you try Aniket solution ? Removing your ~/.m2/repository ?

Comment: I was able to solve that by adding a @ComponentScan to the Application or Configuration

Answer (score 11):

For me, the error was being caused by a missing `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on the Spring class containing the `main()` method entry point which actually starts the Boot application.  Using the following resolved the error:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Likely a corrupt download. Try removing ~/.m2/repository.

Answer (score 4):

You actually just need to change `webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` to `webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK` in your `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

@vdou's answer helped me to resolve my issue.

In addition to adding @EnableAutoConfiguration, I also had to manually add the spring application type:

```
spring:
  main:
    web-application-type: reactive
```

There is obviously something in my dependencies that is causing Spring not to be able to discover the type.

I hope this helps somebody...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, check if in your Application class that contains the main method, doesnt have this:

```
runApplication<Application>{
    webApplicationType = WebApplicationType.REACTIVE
}
```

Then change the "REACTIVE" to "SERVELET", will work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If None of the above solutions work, try adding

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
```

It may help you

```
import org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoader;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another reason this can occur is if you're importing in a configuration class for your test that is not marked with `@TestConfiguration` annotation

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem and it was fixed by doing -

Added in build.gradle -

```
implementation  "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux"
```

Added in `application.properties` -

```
spring.main.web-application-type = REACTIVE
```

And compatibility could be the problem as well so using spring boot version 3.2.0 and   springCloudVersion version as "2023.0.0"
Is still unable to fix the issue with above configurations, try to install Intellij Idea and it would work fine. Use Java 17 for the same.
If it fixes your problem hit up button.